# Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Free Tier 30 GB-months HDD includes standard or SSD persistent disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Free Tier conditions (https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) say that "30 GB-months HDD" is included with a f1-micro VM instance.

But when you create an instance, you can choose a "standard persistent disk" or "SSD persistent disk".

My question is, does the "30 GB-months HDD" include "SSD persistent disk" or only "standard persistent disk"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/): "Standard persistent disks are backed by standard hard disk drives (HDD). SSD persistent disks are backed by solid-state drives (SSD)."

So, to be in the Free Tier you should choose a "Standard Persistent disk" when creating your VM instance.

For future reference, [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) you can find the performance (IOPS and Maximum sustained throughput) differences between these two types of persistent disks.

Comment: yes, this clarifies that HDD indeed means a standard drive, tnx

Comment: Note: the default option when creating an instance with the CLI is HDD. However, on the website, the default is balanced PD which is in between HDD and SSD and not included in the free tier.

Answer (score 4):

With Free Tier you can't use SSD persistent disks but if you signup with Free trial account you get $300 as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial).

With this amount of credit you can use any resources you want. Once the the free credit is consumed, you will have to make a subscription to continue using deployed resources or to create new ones on GCP.